# End(xlUp), but remove bottom 2 rows from selected area?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SelectRangeDown_Discontiguous()
   Range("A1:AH1", Range("c1048576").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 0).Select
End Sub
```

I am using the above macro to select data from the active sheet to copy. However, there is a line free of data and then a footer at the bottom, so I need to reduce the area selected by 2 rows before copying.

Comment: This? `Range("A1:AH" & Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 2).Select` Note that using `Select` is inefficient and usually unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put -2 in the Offset part and put the bracket in the correct place

```
Sub SelectRangeDown_Discontiguous()
   Range("A1:AH1", Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)).Select
End Sub
```

As long as the end row has something in column C.